# Leaflet Draw Plugin: How to get diagonal latlng of a rectangle

Tags: leaflet

I want to get lat long of rectangle in format `"[51.49, -0.1], [51.48, -0.06]"` means only diagonal lat long.

I am using `getLatLngs()`. It gives all four co-ordinates of rectangle.

```
if (type === 'rectangle') {
    pt = layer.getLatLngs();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getLatLngs()`:

```
var latLngs = rect.getLatLngs();
var diagonal = [latLngs[1], latLngs[3]];
```

or you can use `getBounds()`:

```
var bounds = rect.getBounds();
var diagonal = [bounds.getNorthWest(), bounds.getSouthEast()];
```

Comment: thanks..getBounds method works